# ¿Como redireccionar un 'href' en un jsp?

Tags: html, jsp

Tengo un formulario para actualizar varias delegaciones por medio de un `"id"` llamado `"actualizar.jsp"` y para cada delegación tengo una consulta.

al momento de dar click en actualizar los datos para modificar el `id delegación=1` me los muestra y modifica pero lo que quiero es que al momento de acabar la modificación por medio de un `href` me mande a la página de la consulta que quería modificar,

tengo un `href` pero me manda a  la página de inicio, no se como hacerle para que me mande a una consulta en específico.

```
introducir el código aquí  <%
  consulta  conexion = new consulta("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","pasaportes","oppasaportes");
    String query="UPDATE delegaciones SET  GESTION_FIRMA_CONTRATO='"+GESTION_FIRMA_CONTRATO+"' , FIRMA_DEL_CONTRATO ='"+FIRMA_DEL_CONTRATO+"' , NOTIFICACION_DGD = '"+NOTIFICACION_DGD+"'  , CONTRATO = '"+CONTRATO+"'  WHERE id_delegacion = '"+ID_DELEGACION+"'";
    int c=conexion.ejeSentencia(query);
    if(c==1){    



   %>
   <h4>Datos Actualizados Con exito</h4>
   <h5>Fecha y Hora: <%= new java.util.Date() %></h5>
   <%
         }
   %>


   <a href="inicio.jsp">regresar...</a>
```

Funciona la actualizacion, mi único problema es mi href que quiero que regrese a la delegación que ya actualize y no a inicio.jsp

Comment: "me mande a la página de la consulta que quería modificar," a qué te refieres? A qué te refieres con "consulta"? A mí me suena a una SQL, a eso te refieres?

Comment: @user2930137 si mira, mi aplicacion web tiene una pantalla de inicio con un menú de consultas del 1 al 10, de ahi seleccionas la 1 y me manda a la consulta correspondiente, en las 10 consultas que tengo hay un botón de modificar el cual me manda a un solo formulario que esta diseñado para las 10 consultas.

Lo que quiero es que al término de las modificaciones por medio de un botón o un href me regrese a la consulta que corresponde mi modificacion y no a la pagina de inicio, ¿me podrias ayudar?

Comment: Comparte el código, por favor.

Comment: @user2930137 listo!!

Comment: Realmente pedía el menú y la manera en la que "mandabas" de una consulta  a otra xD Pero bueno, quiero suponer que tienes tienes tu página html con tu menú de 10 consultas. Cuando le das clic a una "consulta" cualquier esta te muestra un formulario que estaba oculto en esa misma página html y ya que muestras el formulario y lo llenas y das a "enviar" se actualiza y te manda a esa página que pusiste arriba (lo editado), cuando das en REGRESAR lo que quieres tú es que muestre el formulario que se utilizó para actualizar la información que justo se actualizó?